# Determine ordering of polygon 3D

Tags: 3d, polygon, concave

I have a list of vertices 3D, creating a polygon.
I need to triangulate it and i use the cutting ears algorithm.
My polygons are non-convex, so i need to find the concave angles in the polygon.
I also dont know wich orientation are my polygons ( clockwise or counter clocwise)

Could anyone help me how to determine if is clockwise or counter clockwise

Thank you

Comment: clockwise or counter clockwise depends on the side you're looking the polygon from, it's not absolute in 3d, I think

Comment: Are you using a library (like OpenGL)? If so, you may be able to use something like GLUtesselator. This will scale easily even to non-convex polygons if you ever need it.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably simplest to project the polygon into a convenient plane (say z=0) and then use a method like reinier's.

1) Set all z=0. This won't change the answer.

2) Use a method like reinier's or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165647/how-to-determine-if-a-list-of-polygon-points-are-in-clockwise-order/1165943#1165943) to determine whether the polygon is clockwise or counterclockwise, and therefore whether the cross products "should be" +z or -z.

3) Any vertex with a cross product that points in the "wrong" direction is concave.

Comment: Almost correct, except we need to check that the polygon is not in a plane perpendicular to the XY plane (in which case setting all z to 0 will degenerate it to a line).

Answer (score 0):

use the cross product

[ordering of polygon](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/clockwise/index.html)