# How to find orientation of a bezier curve?

Tags: geometry, orientation, bezier

How to find orientation (cw or ccw) of a closed curve that's formed by Bezier cubic segments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as the orientation of the control polygon. See [How to determine if a list of polygon points are in clockwise order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165647/how-to-determine-if-a-list-of-polygon-points-are-in-clockwise-order) and http://www.cgafaq.info/wiki/Simple%5FPolygon%5FOrientation