# How to determine ring points' orientation correctly?

Tags: math, geometry, polygon

Based on [How to determine if a list of polygon points are in clockwise order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165647/how-to-determine-if-a-list-of-polygon-points-are-in-clockwise-order)

I've come up with the following code:

```
bool PointsClockwise(const std::vector<MyPoint>& points)
{  
  double sum = 0.0;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < points.size() - 1; ++i)
    sum += (points[i+1].x()-points[i].x()) * (points[i+1].y()+points[i].y());

  return sum > 0.0;
}
```

However, this seems to have wrong result in certain cases. Take for example the following ring:

```
LINESTRING(0 119,0 60,694 70,704 72,712 77,719 83,723 92,725 102,723 111,719 120,712 126,703 130)
```

It is in counter-clockwise order, but the function returns true.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed one of the line segments from your summation - namely the one connecting the last point with the first.
Try that:

```
bool PointsClockwise(const std::vector<MyPoint>& points)
{  
  double sum = 0.0;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < points.size() - 1; ++i)
    sum += (points[i+1].x()-points[i].x()) * (points[i+1].y()+points[i].y());

  sum += (points[0].x()-points[points.size()-1].x()) * (points[0].y()+points[points.size()-1].y());

  return sum > 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Right on, forgot the closure :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the case `i == points.size() - 1`, but to do that, you need to do some modular arithmetic in the loop, or else separate out the last iteration. Actually, just initialize `sum` to the last iteration:

```
double sum = (points[0].x() - points[points.size() - 1].x())
  * (points[0].y() + points[points.size() - 1].y());
```

and end the iteration at `i < points.size() - 1`

Comment: Ah. So it isn't. Amending my answer.