# Improve performance of Voronoi volume estimation

Tags: python, performance, scipy, voronoi, scipy-spatial

I need to estimate the volumes associated with a set of Voronoi cells in a multi-dimensional space. From this question [Volume of Voronoi cell (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634993/volume-of-voronoi-cell-python) I tested [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54265278/1391441) and it works, but it is really slow.

In the code below, obtaining the volumes takes up almost 90% of the time:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import time as t

points = np.random.uniform(0., 100., (5000, 4))

s = t.time()
v = Voronoi(points)
print(t.time() - s)

s = t.time()
vol = np.zeros(v.npoints)
for i, reg_num in enumerate(v.point_region):
    indices = v.regions[reg_num]
    if -1 in indices:  # non-closed regions
        vol[i] = np.inf
    else:
        vol[i] = ConvexHull(v.vertices[indices]).volume
print(t.time() - s)
```

That 90% is almost entirely used by the calls to [`scipy.spatial.ConvexHull`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html).

Can this be improved in any way?

Answer (score 0):

The call to `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull` creates a lot of overhead. When calling the attribute `volume` the object has to decide on its outer points first which is essentially the smallest circumference around all the points passed (in this case). Therefore, the use of a function that calculates the surface area of a polygon given n points should be sufficient. See [Area of a convex polygon](https://www.mathwords.com/a/area_convex_polygon.htm) for an implementation of such a function, under the assumption that the voronoi cells are convex (which is usually the case.)

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467972/calculate-area-of-polygon-given-x-y-coordinates) StackOverflow answer for a Python specific implementation.

Comment: Your links point to a two-dimensional approach, and I'm not sure how easy (even possible?) it would be to implement that for a general number of dimensions.

Comment: I suspect there is a general solution for this problem, although I'm not familiar with it. Have you checked the implementation of the `volume` attribute in `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull`? This might give you some ideas.