# Google Maps Android API v2 - Hollow Polygon not correctly drawn

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

The code below doesn't work with Google Maps API v2. The polygons (outer and inner polygons) are drawn with the right border, but the fill color of the outer one is not drawn.

```
PolygonOptions polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions();
polygonOptions.add(outerCoordinates);
polygonOptions.addHole(Arrays.asList(innerCoordinates));
polygonOptions.fillColor(Color.BLUE);
polygonOptions.strokeWidth(1.0f);
```

Does anybody face the same problem?

Comment: Have you checked whether there is a requirement that polygon coordinates are clockwise (or counter clockwise) ordered? Further in polygon filled there are usually two filling algorithms which can be set via option: zero-winding rule, (the other i forgot)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I changed the coordinate direction from clockwise to counterclockwise for the inner polygon and it worked.

Comment: Typing error. Change was from counterclockwise to clockwise for inner polygon.

Comment: I posted an answer from my comment. you then can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether there is a requirement that polygon coordinates have to be clockwise (or counterclockwise) ordered. Try to change the order.

Answer (score 0):

> The vertices must be added in counterclockwise order. [Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/PolygonOptions?hl=es#addAll%28java.lang.Iterable%3Ccom.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng%3E%29)

I wrote a function to determinate if a `List<LatLng>` is clockwise. The code is an implementation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1165943/842697):

```
public boolean isClockwise(List<LatLng> region) {
    final int size = region.size();
    LatLng a = region.get(size - 1);
    double aux = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        LatLng b = region.get(i);
        aux += (b.latitude - a.latitude) * (b.longitude + a.longitude);
        a = b;
    }
    return aux <= 0;
}
```

Before adding the `polygon` points put these three lines:

```
if (isClockwise(polygon)) {
    Collections.reverse(polygon);
}
```