# Tracking the connection of vertices and determening when a polygon is made

Tags: c#, algorithm, geometry, polygon, graph-theory

I'm trying to work on a game mechanic in c# that involves connecting vertices and forming polygons.

There can be any number of 5 - 30 vertices. Each vertice can be connected with a straight line(**The lines cannot intersect**). When the line closes a polygon the inside of the polygon is colored in a specific color. (**You cannot close a polygon if there would be a point inside it during the closing**)

For example two pictures below cannot happen:

[image: First Wrong move][image: Second wrong move]

However, this can:

[image: Correct move]

What i am having trouble with is how to discern the polygon i have just closed and remembering it (in case i close a polygon that shares an edge with it). I can have multiple closed polygons until all lines that can be drawn from each vertice without breaching the intersect rule can be drawn.

I tried remembering lines that were drawn AB, ED, CD, CA etc.. and looking for a cycle, but when i close multiple polygons i need more information to know which polygon has already been closed. But I'm having difficulty figuring out how to do so.

For example (picture below), if the line **n** was drawn i want to find the polygon that was just made.

[image: Example of a move]

Does anyone have any idea how i might achieve this?
Any idea, help, insight would be helpfull.

Comment: This paper might help: *Polygon Detection from a Set of Lines*, http://www.inesc-id.pt/pt/indicadores/Ficheiros/936.pdf

Comment: if you already have the code to check if a valid polygon has been made then any valid polygon that includes the line `n` will be new... I think at least :P

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a bit simplistic, but you can store a `Dictionary<Face,List<Vertex>>` which you can interrogate with linq.

You can simplify it by adding the reverse lookup. `Dictionary<Vertex, List<Faces>>`

**Scenario 1: Path touches edges which are part of the same face**

To test a new path `DC` you get the 2 vertices, D and C and find any faces which contain both. Start with D in the `List<Vertex>` and create the path to C.

Now do the same with `C -> D`.

You now have 2 paths, `D -> E -> C` and `C -> A -> B -> D` both form valid faces using `D -> C` so now you have to enumerate all the vertices and eliminate any faces which contain an existing vertex.

**Scenario 2: Path touches an edge which are not part of any face**

This path is open.

**Scenario 3: Path touches eges which are part of different faces**

Face1: ABDEC
Face2: AGF

Testing the path FC. F is part of Face2 C is part of Face1.

Find intersections: Face1.Face2 == A it's the only point in both lists, this time you get 2 sets of 2 paths.

FA
 FGA

AC
 ABDEC

To go from F to A, these paths multiply

FAC
FGAC
FABDEC
FGABDEC

These faces can now be tested for validity.

It might be easier for this an more complex scenarios (3 faces touching, faces sharing edges) to also keep a graph of all connected edges, this would give you an easier way to detect possible paths between 2 vertices.

Note that ANY path containing 3 vertices forms a possible face which can be checked for validity

Comment: That is what is worrying me, if i have enough vertices that are all connected and i am trying to find the one polygon that was just made, it might turn into too much of a complex operation to go through all of the ones that share same vertices. Since this is suppose to happen after a player draws a line, if it lasts too long i might have to consider different options.

Do you think remembering the connected edges, as well as paths will give a clearer idea of what might or might not be the polygon that was just closed?

Comment: @IvanHorvatin The polygon which was just closed contains the edge that was just formed.  You could easily have the method which tests for new polygon formation return the newly formed polygon. Once you've verified the new edge closes a loop returning the current path/polygon/face is trivial

Answer (score 1):

When a player trys to claim a new edge you can:

- [check that the edge does not cross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect) any of the existing claimed edges;
- perform a breadth-first search of the graph formed by the claimed edges (which are not already on the boundary of two polygons) to see if there is an existing path starting at one end of the new edge which reaches the other end of the new edge - in which case a polygon will be formed; and
- if a polygon has been formed:

  - [check to see if there are any vertices inside the polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/217578/1509264) - in which case the player cannot claim that edge.
  - Each edge has two sides. The interior of the formed polygon will be on one side of each edge along its boundary - you can track this and then any subsequent polygons which are also bounded by one (or more) of those edges must be on the other side of those edge(s) to be a valid selection within your game. If an edge has claimed polygons on both sides then it cannot be on the boundary of any subsequent polygons.

You may need to generate a convex hull around the points to exclude the exterior polygon so that when players are forming polygons they are restricted to the interior of the convex hull.

Comment: How would one calculate on which side a polygon is formed? I am thinking and searching for a way, but i cant seem to grasp the how and why. Could you offer some more insight?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159120/how-to-determine-which-side-of-a-polygon-edge-is-inside-a-polygon-and-which-is. You could put a virtual point at a small offset perpendicular from the centre of the line (ensure the offset is smaller than half the minimum distance between any two points) and project a ray (straight line) from that point in a given direction (for example vertically) if the ray crosses the polygon boundary an odd number of times it is inside the polygon and if it is an even number of times it is outside.