# Find the direction of SVG path

Tags: javascript, svg, geometry

Is there any way to find out the direction of svg path elements i.e clockwise or counterclockwise.

I have d path of semi circle.For example,
path: "M-75 0A75 75 0 1 0 75 0Z"

Another example: M2,2 Q8,2 8,8z

Help me find out its direction or for any svg paths.Suggestions please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if a list of polygon points are in clockwise order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165647/how-to-determine-if-a-list-of-polygon-points-are-in-clockwise-order)

Comment: @MattW. The above example has only two points (-75,0),(75,0) i.e collinear points.Then the above calculation does not stand right ??.I should check the sweep flag of arc command ??

Answer (score 2):

Look at [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands)

```
A   75  75   0                  1                0         75  0
    rx  ry   x-axis-rotation   large-arc-flag sweep-flag    x  y
```

sweep flag 0 corresponds to CCW direction

Comment: @ccprog The above example has only two points (-75,0),(75,0) i.e collinear points.Then the calculation does not stand right https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165647/how-to-determine-if-a-list-of-polygon-points-are-in-clockwise-order ??.I should check the sweep flag of arc command ??

Comment: @Hin Two points cannot be collinear, they just lie on the same horizontal. Their positions has no relation to arc direction. Again  - sweep is already defined in your code.

Comment: what for quadratic curves ?? M2,2 Q8,2 8,8z @MBo

Comment: Q is quadratic Bezier with control point  8, 2 and end point 8,8

Comment: can we know the direction for this @MBo

Comment: Check whether control point is left to start-end vector using cross product. If yes - CW, if right - CCW