# How do you determine if a list of of points in 3D space are in clock-wise order?

Tags: graphics, geometry

```
point[0] = (0,1,1)
point[1] = (1,1,1)
point[2] = (0,0,1)
point[3] = (1,0,1)
```

For examples below, each point above maps to an index in the visualization below.

```
0----------1
|          |
|          |
|          |
3----------2
```

Comment: Your example is in fact 2D.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

If the points are not coplanar, it is even impossible to define an orientation.

If the points are coplanar, you can look at their plane from both sides.

---

If you want this information *with respect to an observer*, project the vertices to the viewing plane (to reduce to 2D) and compute the algebraic area by the shoelace formula. The sign tells you the orientation.

Comment: Assuming they are coplanar, could you explain looking at their plane from both sides?

Comment: Take a sheet of paper and flip it.

Answer (score 2):

**You can but only in respect to some direction ...**

taking your example if you are looking on it as is its CW however if you look at it from behind its CCW ... if you look from sides (perpendicularly so the face is projected to line) we can not tell.

So the usual approach is to do a cross product of the vertices. This will give you normal vector of the face but the direction is determined by the CW/CCW. Now the result compare to reference direction by dot product. So:

```
vec3 p0,p1,p2; // 3 vertexes of your face not on single line
vec3 dir;      // reference direction
float winding = dot( cross( p1-p0 , p2-p1 ) , dir )
```

Now the `winding` sign tells you if the face is CW or CCW in respect to dir. Which one it is depends on your notations. **However this works only for convex polygons (or in convex part of concave ones) !!!**

In computer graphics the reference direction is usually camera view direction. So once in camera local space coordinate system the direction is z axis so inspecting the z coordinate of the cross product is enough. This is known as face culling (skipping polygons with wrong winding in GL set by `GL_CULL_FACE`)...

You can look at the reference `dir` as an axis of rotation aorund which you are determining if the points are CW or CCW ...

Comment: Caution, unless the face is convex, your "winding" test is plain wrong as the triangle 012 can lie inside or outside the face.

Comment: @YvesDaoust +1 good point din't even think OP might be using concave polygons for this... I added note about this to answer.