# Why doesn't my code print from this if condition correctly?

Tags: c, coordinates, math.h

I am writing a program in C which currently does the following:

- takes 4 coordinate pairs in the form (x,y) as input
- calculates the sides formed by two pairs of points, compares the corresponding sides (and diagonals)
- prints out that the points form a rectangle if the corresponding sides are equal

What's not working is, when the order of the coordinates is shuffled, the program is supposed to print out that the points do not form a rectangle.

So for example if the points are `(0,0) (20,0) (0,50) (20,50)`, it's supposed to print that the points do not form a rectangle, since it jumps from `(20,0)` to `(0,50)`. However, the condition I have written to check this doesn't work apparently (see the commented line). What can I replace this condition with to successfully operate?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int x[4];
    int y[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("Point #%d:\n", i + 1);

        if (scanf(" (%d,%d)", &x[i], &y[i]) != 2) {
            printf("Invalid input.\n");
            return 1;
        }

      
        if (!(-100000 <= x[i] && x[i] <= 100000 && -100000 <= y[i] && y[i] <= 100000))
        {
            printf("Invalid input.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    int x1 = x[0];
    int x2 = x[1];
    int x3 = x[2];
    int x4 = x[3];

    int y1 = y[0];
    int y2 = y[1];
    int y3 = y[2];
    int y4 = y[3];

    int isRectangle = 0;

    //the condition
    if ((x1 == y4 && y1 == x4) && (x2 == y3 && y2 == x3)) {
        isRectangle = 1;
    } else if ((x1 == x2 && y1 == y4) && (y2 == x3 && y3 == x4)) {
        isRectangle = 1;
    } 

    if (isRectangle) {
        printf("The points form a rectangle.\n");
    } else {
        printf("The points do not form a rectangle.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine if a list of polygon points are in clockwise order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165647/how-to-determine-if-a-list-of-polygon-points-are-in-clockwise-order)

Comment: The code you are presenting does not do what you claim it does. What if the rectangle "tilted" ?

Comment: The question implies that rectangles are composed of horizontal and vertical lines only. If so: As you follow the corners of a rectangle *in order*, what do you notice about changes to the two components of each coordinate?

Comment: The current check is pretty ad-hoc. The first check would never work, since it basically checks if points 1 and 4 (or 2 and 3) are the same point. The second only checks specific edge cases. What it sounds like is that you're tasked with doing a walk over those points, determining if they end up back in the same spot (whilst ensuring the alternate "walks" are the same length). This is less general than just if 4 points form a rectangle, where order should not matter. If you're bound to only orthogonal shifts in positions (i.e. along the axis, horiz/vertical), then you just need bound checks.

Comment: Does it print anything? Or does it just always print "The points form a rectangle" regardless of the coordinates? We need some more information to answer this question currently.